# "Unable to move the cache" error in selenium webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

While running the selenium webdriver script for chrome browser, I am getting the below error:

```
[2144:7568:0519/130434:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: 0
[2144:7568:0519/130434:ERROR:cache_util.cc(134)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\Prudvi\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\GPUCache to C:\Users\Prudvi\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\old_GPUCache_000
[2144:7568:0519/130434:ERROR:cache_creator.cc(129)] Unable to create cache
[2144:7568:0519/130434:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(589)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
```

Could some one help me out please

Answer (score 26):

I assume you're starting your chrome driver attaching your default profile.

It's not the problem of your chrome driver, It's because you are running another chrome instance while you are starting your selenium webdriver, so some of the files in the profile is locked so that your selenium webdriver can not move it.

I encountered the same problem and shut down all chrome instances before starting my selenium webdriver solved the problem.

Comment: This is the right answer. Make sure that you've closed all chrome background instances.

Comment: what if I want to open multiple selenium driver and all of them attached to the same profile

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with chrome driver installation. After I installed the chrome driver it worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs due to the chormedriver api is not integrated with your project.

JUST DO THESE STEPS:

1. Configure your chormedriver api in your build path ( download from here http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)

2.Go to the project right click ->>> go to build path ---> conf build path --> libraries --> add jar (add chromedriver jar file)

3. now add this code before the chormdriver object call.
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path for your chormedriver api ");

Answer (score 0):

It's because you must install selenium web driver instead of selenium IDE, download both & configure build path with that jar file.

Double check the import files which corresponds to selenium web driver, not selenium IDE.