# Failed to create shader cache entry- error while locating an element by its Css selector

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a simple script in Python using Selenium to detect an element by its Css selector. I am accessing the Google page, and am targeting the input, by its CSS selector, which is input[name=q]

The Chrome page opens as planned, but the issue is that it closes without actually finding the input, and throws the following error in the terminal: ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(237)] Failed to create shader cache entry: -2

I tried running the script when Google Chrome is closed, and even went as far as to close all the Chrome processes in Task Manager, and it still complains about the shader cache entry.

What should I do here?

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Python27\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
fLocator = "input[name=q]"
try:
    searchField = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, fLocator)))
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

[image: Error that I'm getting in the PyCharm's terminal]

Comment: I think this issue caused by chromedriver, I run something but do not locate any element also get this issue
[same issue just access one website using chromedirver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSlSX.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is near perfect. You need to make a small change as follows:

Edit the `CSS_SELECTOR` from:

```
fLocator = "input[name=q]"
```

To:

```
fLocator = "input[name='q']"
```

### Update:

Looking at the error, resurfacing of the error and some research over [these](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/mesa-dev/2017-March/147607.html) few [links](https://github.com/bloomberg/chromium.bb/blob/master/src/content/browser/gpu/shader_disk_cache.cc) and [discussions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/trunk/content/browser/gpu/shader_disk_cache.cc) I feel the `shader_disk_cache.cc` or `shader_disk_cache.h` somehow got corrupted. I think a clean uninstall of Google Chrome (using Revo Uninstaller) and complete disk cleanup (using CCleaner) & finally installation of the latest Google Chrome may get us beyond the error.

Comment: I changed the fLocator by adding the single quotes around q, and it still complains about the cache entry.

Comment: Update: I also renamed my file + the changes with single quotes around the name of the input, and now it's working.

Comment: Weird thing, I tried it 2 mins ago and it was working, and now when I ran it again it complains about the cache entry (yet again). Is it somehow related to my chrome driver, being for 32 bits?

Comment: @Andrei-CristianEne Added an update for you your reference.

Comment: I uninstalled Chrome + ran the CC Cleaner, then installed the latest Google Chrome, and tried it, and it still gives me the shared error. The good news is that when I try to use Mozilla, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the script (your code) and no errors came.

Possibly the problem is of chrome driver, please make sure 32/64 bit version is not causing this issue. Also, please see the following link, it may help:
["Unable to move the cache" error in selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317427/unable-to-move-the-cache-error-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: It might be that the Chromedriver I have installed is the problem, since I have 64 bits Windows, and the version of chrome driver is for 32 bits: 2.9 -> chromedriver_win32.zip. However, on the download url for chromedriver (http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.9/), there is no 64-bit version available.

Comment: whats your operating system? windows 7 or 10 ? also, what chrome version is installed on your system ?

Comment: Google Chrome version: 61.0.3163.100 (64 bits) and Windows 10

Comment: if your file name is "navigate.py" try changing it to "mynavigate.py" and then try to run the code. i ran the same code on my system and i was successful.

Comment: did that, it ran fine the first time, without complaining, and then 2 mins later when I tried to run it again it gave the storage entry error.

Comment: can you clear all your CACHE of your system and web browser ? and then try again ?

Comment: Did that, and still complains about the shader. I even uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome to its latest version, and ran CC Cleaner, it's frustrating. But it works just fine when I use it for Mozilla web driver, so I guess I will stick to this one for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Correct Locator are

Using xpath: `//*[@id='gs_htif0']`

fLocator = `"input[name='q']"`