# Error in texting automated message in whatsapp using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, whatsapp

My code is(studied from geeksforgeeks):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
# Replace below path with the absolute path
# to chromedriver in your computer
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600)
# Replace 'Friend's Name' with the name of your friend
# or the name of a group
target = "Rahul Mehta"
# Replace the below string with your own message
string = "Hi"
y_arg = '//*[@id="side"]/div[2]/div/label/input'
input_y = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, y_arg)))
input_y.send_keys(target + Keys.ENTER)
inp_xpath = '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]'
input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,inp_xpath)))
for i in range(2):
  input_box.send_keys(string + Keys.ENTER)
  time.sleep(1)
```

I am getting the error as :

```
[1436:4360:1017/202620.286:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(237)] Failed to create 
shader cache entry: -2
```

I get the same repeated errors in command prompt when I increase the range. The browser gets opened and then it even searches my friend's name but eventually it  doesn't send the message. Please help me.I have almost wasted one whole day for this yet with no clue on how to proceed further:(

Comment: Do you mind copy/pasting the error message as a text? Please refer to [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Selenium - locating an element by its Css selector issue about caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393818/python-selenium-locating-an-element-by-its-css-selector-issue-about-caching)

Comment: I have added the error message.

Comment: Seeing that you are using `[]` operator to get the n-th element, I think your XPath expression may not be correct. Having the example of the HTML will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too face the same problem and what conclusion I deduced is that, actually, with every new version, the whatsapp changes the way of writing its code to automate the HTML code you have to check the new syntax of HTML. For now what I have come up with is this I don't have any idea until when this code will be valid but for now, it is working fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'F:/chrome driver/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600)

target = '"friend\'s name"'

string = "your message"

x_arg = '//span[contains(@title,' + target + ')]'
group_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
    By.XPATH, x_arg)))
group_title.click()

inp_xpath = '//div[@class="pluggable-input-body copyable-text selectable-text"][@dir="auto"][@data-tab="1"]'
input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
    By.XPATH, inp_xpath)))

for i in range(10):
    input_box.send_keys(string + Keys.ENTER)
```