# How to click a random link from google search results through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Currently using Selenium+ Python and this code:

```
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("how to search the internet")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) # hit return after you enter search text
time.sleep(5) # sleep for 5 seconds so you can see the results
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 873)") 
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//h3)[3]/a').click()`
```

as my code.

What Happens: Goes to Google and types in the words and hits search. Scrolls down a bit and then it clicks the first link

What I want: I want to be able to click a random link from the search result page

How to do this?

Edit: This is what I meant when I said unnecessary:
Unnecessary 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBzFg.jpg

Unnecessary 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4xGq.jpg

These are the only results I want: 
This: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAdHA.jpg

Comment: You'll need to collect the links from the page and then make a random choice from that list.  See the `random` package documentation for the `choice` method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured out how to do collect all the links from the page. However there are some links that are unnecessary. Is it possible to exclude them?

Comment: If you got *unnecessary links* then your selector is not perfect. Use more specific selector to get rid of them

Comment: Hi @KunwarSodhi, what exactly do you mean by unnecessary links? Do you want to edit your post and give us an example of what exactly you need - which links exactly, and we could provide a detailed solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question to `click()` on a random link from google search results, as per your *code trial* if you invoke `window.scrollTo(0, 873)` and then invoke `click()` as in:

```
find_element(By.XPATH, '(//h3)[3]/a').click()`
```

*Selenium* will still try to attempt `click()` on the first match, which may not be your desired *usecase*.

### Solution

Inorder to `click()` on a random link from google search results, you can create a *List* out of the *search results* and then generate a *Random Number* and invoke `click()` through an *index* as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
  from random import randint

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  browser=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  browser.get('http://www.google.com')
  search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
  search.send_keys("selenium")
  search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  my_search_list = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='r']/a[not(ancestor::div[@class='xIleA'])]")))
  myRandomNumber = randint(0, len(my_search_list))
  print(myRandomNumber)
  my_search_list[myRandomNumber].click()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  4
  ```

Comment: Can you ensure you are accessing `http://www.google.com` as your program might be accessing the local google server instance which is probhably not ending with `.com`. In that case you may require to tweak the _xpath_ but the logic remains the same. In this run I got an output as **6**.

Comment: It works!. In this case I got a output of 2. However the first time I ran I got a output of 10 and it didn't work then. Maybe the 10th link isn't on the webpage at the time?

Comment: Yup I just got 10 as a output and it didn't work and said List Index out of range

Comment: Well, till now I got a maximum of **9** only :) but why would you get _List Index out of range_ ? We haven't hard coded any value ...

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IgFlTJN   I have no idea why I'm getting this error

Comment: Hmmm, _Failed to create shader cache entry_ I suppose is a much finer issue with your system os/chores. See this discussion: [Failed to create shader cache entry- error while locating an element by its Css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393818/failed-to-create-shader-cache-entry-error-while-locating-an-element-by-its-css) and the linked discussions.

Comment: Yaa I tried to fix that error. But I am talking about Line 19 and list out of index. Does the shader error have anything to do with this?

Comment: I am pretty much confused by the error as we haven't hardcoded any size for the _List_ as such :( I have executed almost 20 times without any error. Did you `from random import randint`?

Comment: Yup. I think its because the webpage doesn't have more then 10 results?

Comment: Ya it only happens when the code RandomNumber is = to 10. All the other numbers work fine

Comment: See `myRandomNumber` is calculated from the _List_ length, so `my_search_list[myRandomNumber]` can't be **out of range** anyway.

Comment: I tried with searching for youtube instead of selenium. So far it has not gotten to using 10.I think it was a problem with the search?

Comment: Exactly, I even didn't cross 9 for once.