# How to search a keyword in google present in list one by one and extract data

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Lets say I have a list consisting of cities. For example,

`zip = ['newyork','delhi']`

how to search `new york pincode` and `delhi pincode` on google and extract the data.

This 
[search](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=Zck&channel=fs&ei=DwVuXaKGO832rQG6xLO4DQ&q=new+york+pincode&oq=new+york+pincode&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30l5.8789.13949..14325...4.2..0.136.1771.4j12......0....1..gws-wiz.....10..0i71j35i39j0i67j0i131j0i131i20i263j0i20i263j0i22i10i30.0omoHBJAff0&ved=0ahUKEwjiyfulgLTkAhVNeysKHTriDNcQ4dUDCAo&uact=5)
gives the result and there are multiple pincodes present. I only need to capute the first one.

The output I need :

`{Newyork: 10001, Delhi: 110001}`

I tried this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import html5lib
import json
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
url = "https://www.google.com/"
chromedriver = r"C:\Users\me\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
pincodencodee=['newyork','delhi']
for i in pincodencodee:    
    search.send_keys(i)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) 
time.sleep(5) 
driver.quit()
```

Comment: update  you question add  the table schema  for table1 and table2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first zip code has attribute `data-idx` which is running index from 0, so the first zip code will have `data-idx="0"`. You also need to relocate the search bar each time to prevent `StaleElementReferenceException`

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

pincodencodee = {'new york': -1, 'delhi': -1}
for key in pincodencodee.keys():
    search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    search.clear()
    search.send_keys(key + ' pincode')
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    code = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.rl_item[data-idx="0"] .title')
    pincodencodee[key] = code.text

driver.quit()

print(pincodencodee) # {'new york': '10001', 'delhi': '110001'}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your desired output is:

```
{Newyork: 10001, Delhi: 110001}
```

Presumably it is a [Python Dictionary](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary/) which you need to construct with the `Keys` from the supplied list and `Values` from the [Google Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976238/how-to-click-a-random-link-from-google-search-results-through-selenium-and-pytho/51987760#51987760) result. To achieve that you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  cities = ['newyork','delhi']
  search_texts = [city + ' pincode' for city in cities]
  print(search_texts)
  pincode = []
  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  for my_text in search_texts:
      try:
          search = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
          search.clear()
          search.send_keys(my_text)
          search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
          element_text = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='rl_item rl_item_base']//div[@class='title']"))).text
          pincode.append(element_text)
      except TimeoutException as e:
          print(e)
  Dict = dict(zip(cities, pincode))
  print(Dict)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['newyork pincode', 'delhi pincode']
  {'newyork': '10001', 'delhi': '110001'}
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Okay so this is a problem that either requires constant dom structure or heavy regex.

Im not gonna waste time on regex, however i can help you with extracting the code itself.

So how i would approach this is try to execute javascript on the browser so that would be:

```
webdriver.execute_script('script')
```

That by itself is no good, so lets take it a step further. Lets initialize a variable and call it `area_code` so then we can push it to our list, and then pass it into the `execute_script()` function as an argument. Lets also grab the code using javascript.

```
area_code = "0"
webdriver.execute_script("arguments[0] = document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].innerText", area_code )
```

Here in the second line `arguments[0]` is indeed the `area_code` variable which we are setting.

Then you can do either key value or 2D array to store the data.

Comment: @艾瑪艾瑪艾瑪 this will return the first value. If you search for "New York area code" it will load the following page: https://www.google.com/search?q=new+york+pincode&rlz=1C1GCEA_enMK853MK853&oq=new+y&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60l2.1099j0j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: from there i just grab first element and fetch its inner text, put it in the argument and then you can do whatever you want with it,

Comment: Yes, just format the code for your liking and take care of variable names etc.

Comment: in this line of code `pincodencodee=['newyork','delhi']
for i in pincodencodee:    
    search.send_keys(i)`   it is taking two places instead of one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198864/discussion-between--and-supersimplepimpledimple).

Comment: I am at work right now. I wrote the code, if you have coding skills that would just be a copy paste for you at this point.