# Selenium Duplicate Elements marked with ==$0

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, code-inspection

How to handle duplicate elements in selenium, where duplicate elements comes marked with `==$0` ?

Go to www.google.com and search for google search button, I have tried iterator and creating list, but, is this correct way of handling `==$0`

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='Google Search']"));
```

I want to select second element.

Answer (score 2):

### [$0 - $4](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#dom)

The `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and `$4` are the *historical reference* to the last five DOM elements inspected within the Elements panel of [[image]google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) or the last five *JavaScript heap objects* selected in the Profiles panel. `$0` returns the most recently selected element or JavaScript object, `$1` returns the second most recently selected one, and so on.

---

In your usecase, you have inspected the <kbd>Google Search</kbd> button through the Elements panel. So in the *Console drawer*, `$0` has been evaluated and displays the same element as:

[image: $0]

---

A bit more information about your usecase would have helped us to answer your question in a better way. However every element within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) can be identified uniquely using either [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) or [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath).

If your usecase is to *Google Search* any particular term/phrase, you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
searchField.sendKeys("user3245610");
searchField.sendKeys("Keys.RETURN");
```

> You can find a detailed relevant discussion in [How to click a random link from google search results through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976238/how-to-click-a-random-link-from-google-search-results-through-selenium-and-pytho/51987760#51987760)

Answer (score 0):

The visible button that you would like to click is descendant of the div with "FPdoLc VlcLAe" class so you can select it with

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='FPdoLc VlcLAe']//input[@name='btnK']"));
```

[image]

The invisible one is descendant of a div that has class = "VlcLAe" but no "FPdoLc" so that's the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two values while using **//input[@aria-label='Google Search']**

[image]

One of the possible solution is to use: **(//input[@aria-label='Google Search'])[ 2 ]** (the value in the solid brackets i.e. 2 should be without spaces)

Eg - driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@aria-label='Google Search'])[ 2 ]"); //(the value in the solid brackets i.e. 2 should be without spaces)

[image]