# Selenium unable to find DOM node index element on webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, dom

**My goal is to scrape the src link within the video tag on [this webpage](https://mplayer.me/default.php?id=MTc3ODc3). [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmxxZ.jpg) is where I am seeing the video tag along with the link which I want.**

- I know how to grab the information within the tag using

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//video')
```

- But when I tried to find the Xpath of the tag by using the console, I was unable to find it.
- I also tried `driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'video')` but I got `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="6a5b945439665a2261e0bb7cf4a19c8e", element="127606c2-b043-4b55-b8ff-5456bb39a2c3")>` from which I dont know how to get the src link. I tried to use `.text` but it became blank.
- I tried parsing through the page_source and finding the link manually but I still could'nt find it.
- There is a  `= $0` right after the end of the video tag, meaning its a [last selected DOM node index][Selenium Duplicate Elements marked with ==$0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56389906/selenium-duplicate-elements-marked-with-0)
- When I type `$0` or `console.log($0)` into the console I get the video tag with the link.
- What should I do scrape this tag and its contents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the source attribute with:

```
[...]
source = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//video').get_attribute('src')
print(source)
[...]
```

Result in terminal:

```
blob:https://mplayer.me/d420cb30-ed6e-4772-b169-ed33a5d3ee9f
```

See Selenium documentation at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/