# Failed to create shader cache entry: -2 error with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to python and I am learning selenium. I want build a simple code that can search automatically anything from google.com as per the input 
I am accessing an element by name and I am getting the error:

> Failed to create shader cache entry: -2.

Anyone could help me with my code and rectify me what I am doing wrong here??

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from time import sleep


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')

elem = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
time.sleep(5)
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("Python")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Failed to create shader cache entry: -2
```

...is the *Log Entry* generated from the **`int ShaderDiskCacheEntry::WriteCallback(int rv)`** function defined in [shader_disk_cache.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/trunk/content/browser/gpu/shader_disk_cache.cc)

The main issue was the the *shader cache code* **deletes** all but one *timestamp tuple directory*.

As per [Failure to create folder for on-disk shader cache](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100091) the main issue was that the shader cache code deletes all but one timestamp tuple directory.

---

### Solution

As a solution the following steps were taken:

- Move all cache entries to a single cache directory and instead use the timestamp (in future maybe build-id hash) and gpu id as part of the cache entries sha input.
- Remove old entries as the cache approaches its max size. Though this solution makes things a little harder for collection/distribution of precompilled shaders but not unsolvable.
- `util/disk_cache`: hash timestamps into the cache keys

> Instead of using a directory, hash the timestamps into the cache keys themselves. Since there is no more timestamp directory, there is no more need for deleting the cache of other mesa versions and we rely on eviction to clean up the old cache entries. This solves the problem of using several incarnations of disk_cache at the same time, where one deletes a directory belonging to the other.

- This fix submitted on *Sun Mar 12 06:06:00 UTC 2017* should solve this issue with a system upgrade.
- As per best *best practices*:

  - Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
  - Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.45**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
  - Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v70-72*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/notes.txt))

You can find a relevant discussion in [Failed to create shader cache entry- error while locating an element by its Css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393818/failed-to-create-shader-cache-entry-error-while-locating-an-element-by-its-css/46397342#46397342)

Answer (score 0):

probably js keeps moving on and your object is not written on time, I fixed this by adding a sleep.

that is dirty stuff because I am only leeching data from a website, but proper fix is to do an async method and allow it to execute totally before js moves on.